# Font-awesome Icons not loading after connecting to AWS

Tags: html, css, django, amazon-s3, font-awesome

I am doing a project for developing a website. I chose Django for my backend. I have uploaded my static files on Amazon s3 bucket. All my CSS files and images and every static file are loading except the icons from font-awesome. I tried using their CDN. Yet no result.

```
  <link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I see no results whatsoever. The URL of my website:
https://fine-arts-club.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I see your font-awesome icons are showing. so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It is loading now because I removed the downloaded file and applied the CDN of font-awesome.

Comment: I'm having another issue now. I'm using sqlite3 as my database (the django default database) and storing my static files in Amazon S3 bucket. Now while I add images via Django admin the images stay in the website for like a couple of hours then disappears again. I was told heroku is ephemeral so I used S3 bucket but the issue prevails. Do I need to connect to Postgresql that heroku provides?

Comment: Please create a new Question for your new issue.

Comment: I already created. But no answers yet.

Comment: Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538225/images-disappearing-in-heroku-even-after-storing-them-in-s3-bucket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually caused by improperly configured CORS handling.

Open your browser developer tools. If there is an error saying that Font Awesome could not be loaded because it is blocked by CORS policy, this is the reason.

To solve this you need to set the `access-control-allow-origin` HTTP header.

Setting the value to `*` will allow any domain.

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

You can set the Header value to a specific domain. This is usually the best option for files hosted for a specific site.

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.your-domain.com
```

There are two ways to set the CORS header. You can create a policy in your S3 bucket or you can moddify the header using a Lambda@Edge function.

### S3 Configuration

[How to add CORS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html)

[CORS Configuration Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

```xml
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>https://www.your-domain.com</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

### Lambda@Edge Function

You can also add the `access-control-allow-origin` HTTP header using a Lambda@Edge function. It is probably overkill for what you need, but it can be helpful if have a more complex setup.

To do this you need to create a Lambda function at US-East-1.

An example of the code you would use would be something like this...

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

    // Add logic here
    let cors = "something";

    response.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = [{ key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: cors }];

    return response;
};
```

Once you have created the Lambda function you can add hook it into your CloudFront distribution by editing a behavior and adding your function to **Lambda Function Associations** as either "Viewer Response" or Origin Response".

I would recommend using the S3 method for almost all situations.

Comment: I'm having another issue now. I'm using sqlite3 as my database (the django default database) and storing my static files in Amazon S3 bucket. Now while I add images via Django admin the images stay in the website for like a couple of hours then disappears again. I was told heroku is ephemeral so I used S3 bucket but the issue prevails. Do I need to connect to Postgresql that heroku provides?

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

This configuration is working for me perfectly. You can try it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by setting CORS policy on AWS S3.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

Please make sure set AllowedHeaders,AllowedMethods,AllowedOrigins that your website really need.

```
[
        {
            "AllowedHeaders": [
                "*"
            ],
            "AllowedMethods": [
                "GET"
            ],
            "AllowedOrigins": [
                "*"
            ],
            "ExposeHeaders": []
        }
    ]
```