# Images disappearing in heroku even after storing them in S3 bucket

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using **sqlite3** as my **database**, i.e., the django default database. I am told Heroku is ephemeral. So the images stored will be vaporized. So I used **Amazon S3 bucket** for storing all my static files and the images uploaded via **django admin**.
Still the images that I upload via **django admin** gets *disappeared* after couple of hours.

In my **settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = **
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = **
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

In my **models.py**:

```
class Moment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='moments')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Do I need to connect to the **Postgresql** that heroku provides? Or did I make any blunder thus far? The link to my site:
http://fine-arts-club.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Where is your SQLite database stored? If this is on the Dyno as well, then this will be getting 'reset' each Time the Dyno restarts as well. Using Heroku Postgres instead will ensure your database survives when the Dyno is restarted.